# How to switch slots without a computer or using TWRP?

Tags: root-access, termux, ab-partition

I'm working with Android 9 Pie and I have one slot rooted (slot A) and the other is not (slot B). My reasoning to have my phone this way is because I need the non-rooted side to log in to the app I use for my job. (Even though it still works if I log in on slot B and then switch slots via TWRP without logging out).

I've tried the outdated [Switch My Slot](https://github.com/gibcheesepuffs/Switch-My-Slot-Android) app which crashes immediately.

I'm mostly looking for a command I can run via termux to speed things up as opposed to just switching slots in TWRP which takes longer than just a command that would switch slots and reboot. How to switch slots without a computer or using TWRP?

Comment: (off-topic) might you elaborate how to switch slots from TWRP? just curious about

Comment: One way to switch slots from TWRP is to hold the power button and then press Recovery.  My phone then will reboot into twrp blu_spark and prompt me to enter the password to  unencrypt my phone from there I press "reboot" and then press the slot that it is not currently in.

Comment: +1.Similar question for [Android 13](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252459/131553)